# Backfround blink in UIWebView on vertical scroll in iOS 6

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios6

I using UIWebView with `-webkit-column-*` and using vertical scroll (`window.scrollTo(X, 0);` methood) for changed page.

All worked very good in iOS 4.3 and 5. But in iOS 6, when scrolling, I see blinks background in that part of the screen to go scroll
Color of blink is equal to `self.view` (webview is transparent).

I see this question: [ios 6 uiwebview shows background while scrolling a page using jquery scrolltop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578618/ios-6-uiwebview-shows-background-while-scrolling-a-page-using-jquery-scrolltop)
But this does not solve my problem.

How to get rid of this blink?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. Fixed it adding three properties:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Get this solution from [here](http://indiegamr.com/ios6-html-hardware-acceleration-changes-and-how-to-fix-them/)